# How to switch StackPanel items' Panel.ZIndex value with a Control outside?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Maybe this is a stupid asking, but I just wonder how to design this kind of layout:

first of all, I have a MenuList ObservableCollection. So I have to put these menus in to a stackPanel like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
        <Button Content="{Binding ContentText}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding PIndex}" Padding="10" FontSize="20"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

so it looks like this:
[image]

after a while, there's a new bar under this menu added in:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    .......
</ItemsControl>

<Border Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" Panel.ZIndex="10" Height="30" Margin="0,81,0,0"/>
```

Now it's look like this:

[image]

The requirment is, if a button selected, it should on the top of the bar, other unselected buttons should be covered by the bar:

[image]

But the buttons' are in a StackPanel, so they're all based on StackPanel's ZIndex.

My question is, how to design such layout in xaml?

Comment: Let widen our options for such layout: Let me suggest TabControl for this job.

Comment: @tgpdyk I'm a new for wpf, I tried tabControl but confused with the custom template thing... so i decide to create a simple one by myself. Do you have good sample for how to edit control's template?

Comment: You need to do the templates if the stock view is not enough. From your code, you can remove the ItemTemplate and replace the ItemsControl with TabControl. Let me know if what you are seeing is not enough for you. You can do like this: <TabControl Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" DisplayMemberPath="ContentText">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Green"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>

Comment: @oh-my-god have you checked my solution ?

Comment: I accept Willi.Hu's solution only because that is the most close one to my requirement. But Tyress & AnjumSKhan's solutions are much more impressed. - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the renderTransform is better. No need to hard code PIndex in xaml. See below.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
      <Button Content="{Binding}" Padding="10" FontSize="20" Height="30"   Width="100">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1.2"></ScaleTransform>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
</DataTemplate>

<Border Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="30"  Margin="0,150,0,0"/>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Menus { get; set; }
```

EDIT:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
        <Button Content="{StaticResource image1}" Height="30" Width="100">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="Border" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Background="Orange">
                                    </Border>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform"  TargetName="Border">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1.2"></ScaleTransform>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry man, but this solution force scaled the button then changed it's content.

Comment: Yes. . It's a UI effect when you selected the menu. Is it same with your requirement?

Comment: No, it's not. Each tab is a icon actually, scale will destroy the image. But I like your idea, is there any way based on your solution but not destroy the image?

Comment: Yes.Please see new edit. This solution won't destory your image. But maybe you need write some button effect for your controlTemplete of the new button. For example. Hover, Press. I just write the focused for you.

Comment: Your code means separate image and scale action so that scale would not effect on icon? Looks good~ - sorry I'm outside cannot test.

Answer (score 0):

If the bar is literally just a green bar, you can also put it on the DataTemplate as a separate Stackpanel from the button, and then put a Style.Trigger on the Button's stackpanel to increase the ZIndex OnMouseOver. The bar would look seamless even if it is just repeating.

So instead of:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <Button Content="{Binding ContentText}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding PIndex}" Padding="10" FontSize="20"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You will have

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
        <StackPanel >
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" >
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="3"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="{Binding ContentText}" Padding="10" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="2">
            <Border Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

(This doesn't look quite perfect if you run it, but you get the idea)

Comment: hi @Tyress it's a great idea that opened my mind. But unfortunately, that green bar is much more complex than I posted, it's irregularly and not tile image as background. So I want to know are there any updated idea for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Dockpanel as our ItemPanelTemplate is the right choice.
2. Use a Grid with Button and Rectangle (for bottom border) as DataTemplate to show Menu items.
3. Don't apply margin in DataTemplate's Grid in step2 above. Instead use Grid Padding, Button margin for spacing.

DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <Grid Background="DodgerBlue">
        <Button Margin="5 5 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="{Binding ContentText}" Padding="1"  Width="75" GotKeyboardFocus="Button_GotKeyboardFocus" LostKeyboardFocus="Button_LostKeyboardFocus"/>
        <Rectangle  Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="BurlyWood" Height="5" Margin="0 25 0 0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

ItemPanelTemplate :

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DockPanel Height="30" LastChildFill="True"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Use the below code as is :

```
<ItemsControl Panel.ZIndex="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemTemplate}" Margin="0">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
            <Grid Background="DodgerBlue">
                <Button Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="{Binding ContentText}" Padding="1"  Width="75" GotKeyboardFocus="Button_GotKeyboardFocus" LostKeyboardFocus="Button_LostKeyboardFocus"/>
                <Rectangle  Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="BurlyWood" Height="5" Margin="0 25 0 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel Height="30" LastChildFill="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code-Behind

```
public IList Menus { get; set; }
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Menus = new[] { new { ContentText = "Menu1" }, new { ContentText = "Menu2" }, new { ContentText = "Menu3" } };

    this.DataContext = this;
}


private void Button_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel.SetZIndex((Button)e.OriginalSource, 12);
}

private void Button_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel.SetZIndex((Button)e.OriginalSource, 1);
}
```

[image: Menu item with bottom border]

Comment: - oh-my-god have you checked my solution ? -
yes AnjumSKhan I've checked, sorry for no response cuz I think this solution is similar idea of Tyress. But unfortunately, that green bar is much more complex than I posted, it's irregularly and not tile image as background. So i think it's not fit my requirement.